# How to make a discord bot go online using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot. After several tries I still can't get it to go online.

So I'm using a mac and when I ran:

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

I get a message that says "Requirement already satisfied".

**My code:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ("Bot is ready.")
      
client.run('token')
```

What did I do wrong and how do I make my bot go online?

Comment: I guess just run the code with `python3 discord.py` ?

Comment: aren't you also supposed to host the bot?

Comment: Have you tried running your code? Do you get any errors when you run it? If so, what errors do you get?

Comment: Based on what you've described, it appears that you are a beginner python programmer. In this case, I highly recommend you to not attempt to make a discord bot first, as discord.py uses many advanced python features that beginners haven't learned yet. Instead, you should start with a tutorial for beginners to learn python basics before making a discord bot.

Answer (score 2):

As nuclio said, I personally think that naming your file "discord.py" is really hard to use, which means it would require more than you think to make your bot run using that name.
If you have regenerated your bot token, make sure to update your code with the latest token, if not, your bot will never be online. On my codes, I have an extra line in between the imports and prefix sections. You can give that a try, but I don't think it will make a difference. Reply back to me if you are still having trouble

Answer (score 0):

Always please clarify your questions briefly i.e. what error you got, how you ran the code, etc.

Check Following Things Wherever You Run A Bot:

1. You have the correct code, which means you don't find any errors ofc.
2. You have entered the right Bot `Token` in your py file.
3. Saving your bot file with name `discord.py` is **not** recommended.
4. You are in same directory as of the example.py file, and used `python3 example.py` in terminal.

Answer (score -1):

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ("Log : "+str(client.user))

client.run('token')```
````

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?